# REGEXP and expressions beginning at start of string or with a separator

Tags: regex, string

I'd like a REGEXP that only picks up a substring that either starts at the beginning of the string or is preceded by a space or separating character. How does this work?

For example,

`[ _^]Smith`

seems to be almost it!

Comment: No, the caret `^` is not a character, it's an `anchor` and shouldn't be in the character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(^|[ _])Smith
```

`^` (start) or one of `[ _]` followed by `Smith`

(`|` is the `or` operator)

Comment: @Manji: Thanks. Putting `^` inside `[]` but not at the start makes it literal perhaps. I had tried `([ _]|^)Smith` without a match. However, I get plenty of matches with `[ _]Smith`. How come?

Comment: @manji: C. I'm using `regex.h`, and calling `regexec` and `regcomp`. Your suggestion matches in Java and Python (just tested it), but not in my application which is very odd. Any idea what's up?

Comment: Each language has it's own regex features and syntax (similar but not the same) (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Comment: @manji: Thanks for the link, I'll check this out asap. It might explain this.

Comment: @manji: I've tried various things. `\([ab]|[ _]\)Smith[ _,.]` and `([ab]|[ _])Smith[ _,.]` don't return anything, but `[ _]Smith[ _,.]` does. Maybe `C` has its own group characters. Or there are flags that block these. Hmm.

Comment: I'm pushing for something like this, but it's failing to pick up: `(^|[ _])Smith([ _,.]|$)`

Comment: Also, I've tried `[ _]Smith[ _,.]|abcdef` to test `|`, getting no results, and `([ _]Smith[ _,.])` to test grouping, with no results. Odd? I'm in `REG_BASIC` mode. Hmm.

Comment: Which is why! Switching to `REG_EXTENDED` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
^[ _]?Smith
```

`^`- beginning of line
`[ _]?` - space or underscore 0 or one time

Comment: Thanks. I thought `?` meant match zero or one of the preceding expression. It must match one in my case.

Comment: But there is 0, if line just starts with Smith, right? You want to match just `Smith`?